# Animate and move a view

Tags: android, animation

I have a layout containing several buttons. I want to move this layout to a different position on screen using an animation. When I use a `TranslateAnimation`, the layout appears to move however the button press events are still only triggered from their old location. I have attempted to then adjust the view's `LayoutParams` in the `onAnimationEnd` event - this only resulted in some horrible looking snapping effect when the animation completed. No other answers seem to give a definitive solution to this problem.

How can I move a layout using an animation whilst also ensuring their onClick events are triggered from their new location?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ObjectAnimator it will actually move your Button with listener attached to their new positions

```
ObjectAnimator moveButtonAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layout, "translationX", 0, 200f);
        moveButtonAnimator.start();
        moveButtonAnimator.setDuration(1000);
```

Comment: How would you modify the X and Y values simultaneously in one animation?

Comment: The problem I'm having is that the animation appears to be instant, regardless of what value I pass to the setDuration function. This happens both when the setDuration is before and after the start() function (I assume setDuration should be before start).

Comment: can you check adding animationlistener using addListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener)

Comment: Adding a listener does not have any effect on the duration.